Sorting a Funnel in Power BI on a custom column
I am trying to create a Funnel in Power BI. I created a custom column name "StageOrder" which will have below code
StageOrder =
Switch(
TRUE(),
'Table_Name'[column_name]  = "New", 1,
'Table_Name'[column_name]  = "Marketing Engaged", 2
'Table_Name'[column_name]  = "Marketing Qualified", 3,
'Table_Name'[column_name]  = "Sales Accepted", 4,
'Table_Name'[column_name]  = "Sales Qualified", 5,
'Table_Name'[column_name]  = "Opportunity", 6,
'Table_Name'[column_name]  = "won", 7,
BLANK()
)

When I see the funnel in the power BI front end report, I try to sort the funnel based on StageOrder column, but that column is not available for sorting. Below is how my funnel is coming up.

I have gone through some of the articles to see if custom sorting is possible in Power BI and tried some of the solutions as well like use the StageOrder column in the tooltip filter. I tried that but that is coming as countOfStageOrder or DistinctCountOfStageOrder or AverageOfStageOrder like that. Below is the link i went through to solve this but did not work for me.
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Sorting-a-funnel-chart/m-p/3775403
I am not able to sort this funnel based on the stageOrder precedence I gave. Can someone please help me to overcome this issue?
Thanks.

One of the "simplest" ways you can use to solve this issue and the one I use pretty much all the time is appending the "Order code" to the name of the column and then you use it to sort:


you can try to manually create a dim table

sort stage by order and create relationship between dim table and your fact table.
At last, you can drag the column in the dim table into the funnel visual.
